# selecting inverse an Inner Border on photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a way to select an inner border in Select Inverse?

Here is one example

[image: http://snag.gy/I9Z8r.jpg]

I need to select the border pointed by the red arrow. With the basic select inverse both borders pointed by the blue and red arrow are selected.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select > Inverse, then deselect the outer border by holding down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key and dragging the Rectangle Marquee Tool over the edges.

There's often no command to select something specific and one needs to do some manual addition or subtraction of the selected area to get the selection you want.

Comment: scott can you show with video or images because i cant figure how to make ty